# Using Python unable to unzip .mdf files only

Tags: python, zip

Using Python trying to unzip .mdf files from multiple zip files in the same directory. The below code is not finding any .mdf files in the .zip files, because of how I have written it. It is looking at the .zip file not what is in them (I think). But I'm not sure how to amend it to get what I need. New to Python clearly.

```
import zipfile
import os

os.chdir(working_directory)

for file in os.listdir(working_directory):
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(file):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as item:
            if file.endswith('.mdf'):
                item.extractall()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are checking if `file` - which is the zip file - ends with `.mdf` or not. Which obviously won't work.

You need to look inside the zip file. Once you have the zipfile open, you can call the [`namelist()`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zipfile.html#zipfile.ZipFile.namelist) method to get the list of names of the members of the zip file.

```
import zipfile
import os

os.chdir(working_directory)

for file in os.listdir(working_directory):
    if zipfile.is_zipfile(file):
        with zipfile.ZipFile(file) as item:
            for member in item.namelist():  # go through members of the zip file
                if member.endswith('.mdf'):
                    item.extract(member)    # extract only the mdf file
```